# Find text in column and send email only one time when found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to make a google script that searches for text (given in cell C2) in column A and send an e-mail (only once) to addres given in cell C3 when the text is found.

Column A exists of text results from an importXML formula.

I have searched and searched but i cant find it, and im too much of a coding newb to even get started :( Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It isn't clear whether you want to check for a perfect match between cell C2 and cells in column A... My answer below took the perfect match option, if you need to look for a partial match just let me know and I'll edit the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a example of how this can be done, I used a background color to mark the cells in column A for which a mail has already been sent (to avoid multiple sending).

It sends a mail to the spreadsheet user and to address in C3 as well but you can of course adapt it to your needs.

```
// test sendMailOnCondition


function sendMailOnCondition(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var condition = sh.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var email = sh.getRange("C3").getValue();
  Logger.log(condition);
  var valuesInColumnA = sh.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var colorsInColumnA = sh.getRange("A1:A").getBackgrounds();
  for (var n=0;n<valuesInColumnA.length;n++){
    Logger.log(colorsInColumnA[n][0]);
    Logger.log(valuesInColumnA[n][0]);
    if(valuesInColumnA[n][0]==condition && colorsInColumnA[n][0]=='#ffffff'){
      colorsInColumnA[n][0]="#DDD";
      MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),"test mail","Row number "+Number(n+1)+" has value "+condition);// remove this line if you don't need it
      MailApp.sendEmail(email,"test mail","Row number "+Number(n+1)+" has value "+condition);
    }
  }
  sh.getRange("A1:A").setBackgrounds(colorsInColumnA);// update cells colors
}
```

**EDIT** : for safety and to avoid sending many emails erroneously when cell C2 is empty (which just happened to me while testing ;-) you can add a third condition to the 'if' statement : `condition !=""`

the line becomes :

```
if(condition !="" && valuesInColumnA[n][0]==condition && colorsInColumnA[n][0]=='#ffffff'){
```

Comment: I like it. At first I was concerned as to whether the colors would follow the cells if sorted. In the simple test I did they seem to follow just fine. Saves an extraneous email Status column in the data.

Comment: thank you Michael :-) do you like the grey color too ? I was hesitating on the color choice ... (XD) And yes indeed, the background color is perfectly reliable, I use it very often as an easy to use flag.

Comment: Hey Serge, I think gray is good. Especially for the colorblind. Also, I can see the need for your edit, especially with use of open ended ranges.

Comment: How the hell did you guess that I am actually colorblind ? I'm pretty sure I never mentioned that... :-).  I'm currently receiving 999 emails into my inbox... Helping on SO is a risky job sometimes !

Comment: Wasn't personal. Being hounded by all the accessibility posts seems to be having an effect. I suppose that's a good thing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and specific answer :) I have changed some in the sheet to make it more easy, i think. Below you will find the sheet. So IF cell A1 = 1 i want it to send an email to the email addres in cell  E2 (both to be found in sheet name " Search". I think the problem lies in sending the email only once when cell A1 = 1. Thansk so much for your help and i hope you like the idea of  what this sheet will do. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PrcDi96RPLQ5a8FWGl4589Gr4I7OewCeKO02hgdSpys/edit?usp=sharing